# Locking a Drawing button with script attached

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, edit

VERY new to all this. I created a button in Google Sheets from Insert Drawing, with a script attached. However, any user can right-click and edit the button. How can I prevent editing, yet allow users to click the button to run the script? I also need users to be able to edit many of the cells in the sheet.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Are there 2 questions in your question? 1. `How can I prevent editing, yet allow users to click the button to run the script?`. 2. `I also need users to be able to edit many of the cells in the sheet.`.

Comment: @Tanaike Question is "prevent editing on the drawing/button, while allowing editing on the cells"

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. In that case, I think that using a cell as the button using `onSelectionChange(e)` and/or using a checkbox as the button using `onEdit` might be suitable rather than using an image as the button. But I think that this might not be the direction OP expect. So I would like to also think of other direction.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the mentioned solutions in the comments, you could also use the Menu to add the action for running the script.

The user would go to the custom menu item and click to run the script. This way you can dislocate the sheet/range protection from the script running.

See [Custom Menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)